# UrlGenerationException (Missing required parameters for [Route])

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't know where this error came from it says. I got this error when I tried to update my records. It works properly and updating into my database but getting this error. It says that that missed something in my parameter. I think my error is `return redirect()->route('account.show');` when I tried to redirect to my **show** view after updating. But when I redirect to other works fine. Any opinions?

> Missing required parameters for [Route: account.show] [URI: show/{id}].

I have 3 blade template. **search**, **edit** and **show**.

search.blade.php - To show all the records.

```
@foreach ($result as $row)
    <tr class = "success">
        <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->middle_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->username }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href = "{{ route ('account.show', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info">View</button></a>

            <a href = "{{ route ('account.edit', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>

            <a href = "{{ route ('result.destroyEmployee', $row->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Archive</button></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

edit.blade.php - Here where I got the error after hitting the submit button which is **Save**

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.edit', $result->id) }}">

<h3>Edit Employee</h3>
<hr>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->email }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->username }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Save</button>

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

show.blade.php - Textfield's will just place the value of the records.

```
<div class = "col-md-6">
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.show', $result->id) }}">

<h3>View Employee</h3>
<hr>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" placeholder = "{{ $result->email }}" readonly>

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "{{ $result->username }}" readonly>

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Routes:

```
//READ
Route::get('/search',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.search',
]);


//SHOW
Route::get('/show/{id}',
[
    'uses' => 'AccountController@showEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.show',
]);

//EDIT
Route::get('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@editEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);


//UPDATE
Route::post('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@updateEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);
```

Comment: `"{{ route ('account.show', ['result' => $result->id]) }}"` should do the trick. When `routes` accept parameters, the `route()` helper will accept the parameters as an array passed as the 2nd argument. You don't need to do `'key' => 'value'` mapping if you don't want.

Comment: What's the difference if I passed the `'result'` as key in my `route()`? I tried to run your snippet but when I hit the submit button is says `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.show', $result->id) }}">
```

To:

```
 <form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" action="{{ url('edit/'. $result->id) }}" method="POST">
```

Then you have to pass the route parameters as second argument to route. Something like this: `return redirect()->route('account.show', [$id])`

*I would recommend you to use laravel collective form: https://laravelcollective.com/

With laravel collective you can do something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('account.show', $result->id))) !!}
```

Comment: It's not working it says `syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Another error says `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

Comment: try now with `url` method

Comment: I still didn't try the laravel collective. I run your updated post still saying `Missing required parameters for [Route: account.show] [URI: show/{id}].`

Comment: I think my error is `return redirect()->route('account.show');` it won't redirect to my `show` view so I can see if I updated properly. But when I redirect to other view it's working.

Comment: So you need to pass the parameter to the account.show root. If so it will work

Comment: How can pass the parameter in my account.show? Appreciated your time.

Comment: I think you can pass the route parameters as second argument to route. Something like this: `return redirect()->route('account.show', [$id])`;

Comment: Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects `// For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}

return redirect()->route('profile', [1]);`

Comment: It works bro!! Why I need to pass my `$id` in the route ()? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: If you look at your routes `Route::get('/show/{id}',` the id is require to works this root. If you want you can pass optional parameter

Comment: Appreciated your tips bro. Glad you help! :)

Comment: It's my pleasure bro :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('admin.edit',compact('post','id');
```

Comment: please add an explanation how this code solve the question

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.